# Hibernate not updating schema automatically

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am using SpringBoot with Hibernate. I have 2 Postgres datasources. I have an existing database (pims) and a new database (powwow), and some entities. When I start up SpringBoot, I would like it to automatically create the tables in the new powwow database, however it is  not doing so.

**application.properties**

```
# pims datasource
spring.datasource1.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource1.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pims
spring.datasource1.username=postgres
spring.datasource1.password=postgres
# powwow datasource
spring.datasource2.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource2.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/powwow
spring.datasource2.username=postgres
spring.datasource2.password=postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
#spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource2.dbcp2.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource2.dbcp2.validation-query=select 1
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
# logging
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Example entity:

**PowWowActivityEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "powwowactivity")
public class PowWowActivityEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "activity_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long activity_id;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
```

**Output**

```
2022-08-16 09:19:13.227  INFO 65945 --- [           main] com.clubtravel.powwow.PowWowApplication  : Started PowWowApplication in 11.544 seconds (JVM running for 12.617)
2022-08-16 09:19:13.255 DEBUG 65945 --- [   scheduling-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(*) as col_0_0_ from powwowglaccountmapping powwowglac0_
2022-08-16 09:19:13.269 DEBUG 65945 --- [        Async-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into powwowactivity (comment, create_date, status, user_name) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
2022-08-16 09:19:13.272 TRACE 65945 --- [        Async-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [Server started on HOST: Richards-MacBook-Pro.local.]
2022-08-16 09:19:13.273 TRACE 65945 --- [        Async-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Aug 16 09:19:13 SAST 2022]
2022-08-16 09:19:13.274 TRACE 65945 --- [        Async-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [Info]
2022-08-16 09:19:13.274 TRACE 65945 --- [        Async-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [system]
2022-08-16 09:19:13.281  WARN 65945 --- [        Async-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2022-08-16 09:19:13.281 ERROR 65945 --- [        Async-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "powwowactivity" does not exist
```

**Question**

I thought by adding the following line, the new tables would automatically be created by updating the schema.  Any ideas? Is this not working because I have more than one datasource?

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it was not working is because i have  2 datasources defined. If i change the config to update, it works (`properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");`):

```
    @Bean(name = "powwowEntityManager")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean powwowEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(powwowDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.clubtravel.powwow.entities.powwow" });
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
//        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
//        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        logger.info("Setting spring.datasource2 (powwowEntityManager) hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = "+env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto")+" and hibernate.dialect = "+env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        return em;
    }
```